# Why can't I plot this surface?

Tags: plotting

I can't plot (x^z)-(y^z)=x*y. I've tried it with Geogebra and with

```
Plot3D[x^z - y^z == x*y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

in Mathematica, but in both images only appears the axes.

Is there any other Mathematica tool to do it?

I'm started to think that the function is "non-plottable" in some mathematically meaning. Is that possible? Well, it is plottable for any constant z I've tried (I mean setting a value of z and making it a curve), but its shape changes a lot even between very close values... Do "non-plottable" functions exist?

Any idea will help, thank you!

Comment: Try `ContourPlot3D[x^z - y^z == x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: That worked, but anyway, do "non-plottable" functions exist?

Comment: I notice that what mathematica shows does not fit with what geogebra shows slice by slice. I mean that visually the intersecction of what mathematica shows and the plane z=constant is sometimes different of what geogebra shows if you replace z with that constant.

Comment: Perhaps of note for you is that *Mathematica* always takes the principal value for $x^y$; e.g. $(-8)^\frac13\ne-2$.

Answer (score 3):

`Plot3D` requires an *explicit* function $z(x,y)$ to be plotted.  In other words, if you want to plot $z = \sin(x) \cos(y)$, you would give the command

```
Plot3D[ Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

If you only have an *implicit* relationship between $x$, $y$, and $z$, then `ContourPlot3D` is a better choice (as noted by J.M. in the comments):

```
ContourPlot3D[x^z - y^z == x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

Note, however, that the results may be "low-resolution", since Mathematica must now (effectively) search through 3-D space to find points where this equation is satisfied, rather than just calculating $z$ for a variety of points $(x,y)$.  You can tell Mathematica to use more points to construct its surface by using the `PlotPoints` option, but be aware that this will take longer.

Answer (score 0):

As relations are implicit we can use ContourPlot3D. By changing plotting order we could get further insight including domain and *real possible* surface ranges. There are only two nappes representing the surface that are real and so plottable, shown at right for domain $ {(x,0,1),(y,0,1),(z,-1,1)}.$

[image]

```
aa = ContourPlot3D[
  x^z - y^z == x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
bb = ContourPlot3D[
  x^z - y^z == x y, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
cc = ContourPlot3D[
  x^z - y^z == x y, {z, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
Show[aa, bb, cc]
```